# mysql basic insert statement error 1064

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query:

```
INSERT INTO user ('username', 'password', 'email', number) 
VALUES ('user123', '123', 'email123@hotmail.com', 2)
```

and I get the error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''username', 'password', 'email', space) VALUES('user123', '123', 'email123@hotmail.com', 2)

There is also an auto increment field (mediumint), which obviously is not mentioned in the sql statement. Could it be it?

Please help me solve this.

Comment: Backtics should be used instead of single `'` quotes for escaping field or table names

Comment: The error message does not quite correspond to what you specified in your question: "username' (note the different quotes) instead of 'username', space instead of number.

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks (to the left of the "1" key) instead of quotes there:

```
INSERT INTO user (`username`, `password`, `email`, `number`) 
VALUES ('user123', '123', 'email123@hotmail.com', 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Write quote in column name

```
INSERT INTO user ('username', 'password', 'email', 'number') 
VALUES ('user123', '123', 'email123@hotmail.com', 2)
```